# Navigate to PPT Slide by its ID or Name instead of Number

Tags: vba, powerpoint

`ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide x` requires us to enter the slide number, which is varying. If I refer it to Slide Number 3 and then move the position of Slide 3, the code wouldn't refer to that slide anymore.

How do I overcome this by referring to the SlideID or SlideName instead of Slide Number.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to be able to go to a particular slide in the presentation regardless of where it may appear in the presentation (ie because other slides have been added before it or it's been moved to a different position).

If so, you could tag the presentation with the slide's SlideID:

```
ActivePresentation.Tags.Add "IndexSlide", Cstr(lSlideID)
```

(where IndexSlide is any convenient name you've assigned to the slide; you can have multiple tags for different slides you want to track. And lSlideID is, of course, the slide's SlideID

You'd need to write a function to retrieve the slide's SlideIndex, given the SlideID and call it like so (aircode ... you might have to move/remove a paren or two):

```
ActivePresentationSlideShowWindow.View.GoToSlide ( _
  SlideIndexFromSlideID(cLng(ActivePresentation.Tags("IndexSlide")))
```

This gets the tag named IndexSlide from the presentation which is the SlideID of IndexSlide, converts it to a Long (tags are strings), passes it to your SlideIndexFromSlideID function, which returns the slide's current SlideIndex ... for you to GoToSlide with.

[Later: adding the needed function for returning SlideIndex]

```
Function SlideIndexFromSlideID(lSlideID As Long) As Long

  SlideIndexFromSlideID = ActivePresentation.Slides.FindBySlideID(lSlideID).SlideIndex

End Function
```